# CSS margins not center with auto but works with text-align

Tags: css

Why is my text not being centered when i am using the margin to center it(IT WORKS WHEN I USE - `text-align : center`) :

here is the code and the screenshot :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angad's website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
      <img src="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
      <h1>I'm Angad</h1>
      <p>a student </p>
      <img src="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
      <img src="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-image">

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS TO THIS :

```
    h1{
  background-color: #ffe3fe;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

RESULT :

[image: RESULT OF TEXT NOT BEING CENTER:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a width as well. In the browser's mind, this is already centered. Here is an example:

```
h1{
  background-color: #ffe3fe;
  margin: auto;
  width: 8em;
}
```

Comment: THANKS A TON , IT WORKED!!